# Python .execute() not executing Postgresql query

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, execute

I am trying to update a database from a csv file. I am able to connect to the database, run through the lines that are in the csv, compose the desired SQL line, but for some reason it never hits the Postgresql DB. Console and pycharm show no errors.

Here is the .py

```
import csv
import psycopg2
filename = 'C:\dev\student_feedback\student_feedback\student_feedback.csv'
fields = []
rows = []
host='localhost'
port=5432
database='ipfeedback'
user='postgres'
password='#########'
def import_student_survey_csv():
    print('Maybe Updating surveys...')
    def doQuery(connection):
        cur = connection.cursor()
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            fields = next(csvreader)
            for row in csvreader:
                rows.append(row)
                nrows = rows.pop()
                qry = (f"INSERT INTO ipfeedbackdb_studentsurvey ({fields[0]},{fields[1]},{fields[2]},{fields[3]},{fields[4]},{fields[5]},{fields[6]},{fields[7]},{fields[8]},{fields[9]},{fields[10]},{fields[11]}) VALUES ({nrows[0]},{nrows[1]},{nrows[2]},{nrows[3]},{nrows[4]},{nrows[5]},{nrows[6]},{nrows[7]},{nrows[8]},'{nrows[9]}','{nrows[10]}','{nrows[11]}');")
                print('QRY', qry)
                cur.execute(qry)
            csvfile.close()
    myConnection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password, dbname=database)
    doQuery(myConnection)
    myConnection.close()
import_student_survey_csv()
```

the .csv

```
added,spid,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,best_part,improve,comments
21021,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"qwe","qwe","qwe"
21021,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"asd","asd","asd"
21021,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"x","x","x"
21021,12345,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"x","x","x"
```

the table data
[image: Destination Table]

the db structure
[image: DB Structure]

Comment: There is no `commit` done.

Comment: This took care of it. If you repost as an answer I can mark it as a good answer

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I will not post as answer as this is actually a duplicate question that already has many answers, thanks though.